# Japanese anime movie, includes a sword and some gems, and a dragon-like friend

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this movie when I was a kid and never discovered it again.

It’s about a boy whose father left him after his divorce from the mother, the kid enters a world somehow where he has a big sword he needs to keep searching for precious stones to fill it with. it has certain holes that look like each stone shape! I also remember the kid going to eat with his mythical (dragon-like friend), and he gets stuck in the restaurant because the crazy restaurant lady won’t let him leave without finishing huge amounts of food!

The kid also gets bullied so I’m guessing the the swords journey is to teach the kid how to deal with all of this...

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! In about what year did you watch it?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161632/story-id-lengthy-ya-fantasy-novel-where-a-teenager-quests-through-a-fictional (about the book on which the anime is based)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly *Brave Story* (2006)?

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1681/Brave_Story?referer=malupdater):

> When 11-year-old Wataru's father leaves home and his mother is taken ill to the hospital, he decides to change his fate by traveling through the door shown to him by his friend Mitsuru. In a land of magic and monsters, Wataru must summon all his courage and embark on a journey with several comrades to meet the Goddess of Destiny and change this "mistaken fate."

There's a scene taking place in a restaurant, with a dragon-like creature, describing an "aunt Yuna" who won't let you leave if your plate isn't empty.

[image: Boy and lizard looking pal]

---

Found with the Google query `anime movie sword gems slots site:myanimelist.net`, which returned [this solved story-id thread there](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1382369&show=0), which was looking for this movie. Description given:

> A boy gets transported to another reality where he meets a guardian or gate keeper (I think the guardian guy is a frog) and it turns out he fulfills some sort of prophesy and **if he can find all of the gems and slot them on his sword** the goddess of this world will grant him his wish but there's a twist, another boy from his school has already arrived in this world and he has a head start.

Comment: Omg, Thank you so much, I’m Arab so when I was searching, it didn’t cross my mind to use the word (slots), I used stones and sword which kept leading me to the (pulling a sword from the stone) story! Thank you so much for bringing back a part of my childhood, for years I couldnt find it, bless you! ❤️♥️❤️♥️

Comment: @Safaa you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :)