# A 80s-90s anime/cartoon where MC carries a sword in which can place different gems that grant different powers

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

The story goes about a young boy who carries a sword in which he can place different gems of different colors (one at a time, placing a new one ejects the current one) and they provide special powers to the sword attacks. He starts collecting gems so he can switch them mid-combat to grant different powers.

There is a side kick which is a girl. The final episode is a big battle that goes into the stratosphere and the MC places either a super-powerful-gem into the sword or all of them at the same time (even though there is only one slot for a gem), something like that.

Probably it was anime but it's too far back in the past to be 100% sure.
It was shown in Spain during the early 90s on public TV, but it was most probably imported.

Edit: it is neither Shin Hakkenden, nor Brave Story.

Comment: Sounds like _Brave Story_ (2006). And if that's the correct answer, then this question is a duplicate of this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204621/japanese-anime-movie-includes-a-sword-and-some-gems-and-a-dragon-like-friend

Comment: It is not Brave Story. In brave story he must add stone by stone, in the one I mean the sword only allows 1 stone at a time, in the center.

Comment: Do you remember anything visual? Character ages, whether they're tall, short, dressing, hair colour, eye colour, hair length, even the style of drawing (is it closer to old japanese animation like Ranma, Sailor Moon, or Spriggan). The world in which they are (does it look medieval-ish, RPG-ish, modern, retro-futuristc). Anything that would help searching on websites like my anime list for example.

Comment: Character ages: MC was about 14, male, sidekick girl about the same. 
Style of drawing was like Sailor Moon if I recall correctly. I was too young and I did not know the difference back then.
The world was RPGish: monsters, magic, etc... no firearms.
I remember too that the green gem invoked a dragonish aura in the sword. And another gem would make the MC switch gender

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be [Legendary Brave Swordsman Yaiba](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaiba).

[image: yaiba]

MC is quite short/young.

MC has a sword which has a space in its hilt for different orbs, which provide different powers.

List of those can be found [here](https://yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Raijin_Sword). But they include things like giving the MC auras such as flame or electricity.

There is one orb that allows MC to change into other people or things (which includes changing genders, but doesn't have to be).

Released in Japan in 1993, so timeline fits.

Has a female companion for most of the show.

Merges two magic swords to make a more powerful sword near the end (as opposed to merging orbs).

Comment: Yes!!!! For years I've wanted to know the name and I've spent hours Googling it with no avail. You made my day!!!