# Anime where the mc's friend sister dies and he goes to another world to collect orbs that he puts in a wand to get a wish

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, isekai

I saw this anime around 2015-2016 my memories are foggy and I unfortunately don't remember how the characters looked liked but I think that it was an isekai anime, where the mc and his friend were going to a high school. In the anime the mc and his friend somehow found a gate that leads to another magical world.

I also can remember that the mc's friend sister died and the friend went to the magical world where he tried to collect orbs that he put in a wand. If you collected all the orbs you would get a wish and the friend wanted to wish for his sister to come back alive.

I also think there was something with the mc's dad. I think something happend to him and mc tried to find out what happened.

At the end the friend almost had all the orbs and was fighting against the mc. And at the end of the fight the friend decided to kill himself instead of defending the mc.

After that the mc had all the orbs and could make a wish, I don't know anymore what he wished for but he fell asleep and when he woke up everything was back to normal and his friend was back alive.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

As per [Japanese anime movie, includes a sword and some gems, and a dragon-like friend](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204621/japanese-anime-movie-includes-a-sword-and-some-gems-and-a-dragon-like-friend?noredirect=1&lq=1), this may be *[Brave Story](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1681/Brave_Story?referer=malupdater)* from 2006.

> When 11-year-old Wataru's father leaves home and his mother is taken ill to the hospital, he decides to change his fate by traveling through the door shown to him by his friend Mitsuru. In a land of magic and monsters, Wataru must summon all his courage and embark on a journey with several comrades to meet the Goddess of Destiny and change this "mistaken fate."

### Trailer

He slots the pearls into a sword, but otherwise it matches.