# Manga with characters that fight for pearls and must collect 5 to make any wish from the Goddess

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime, isekai

I am looking for a manga where characters are summoned throughout the world (isekai) and have to fight each other in order to gain the pearl held by their opponents. If anyone in the world achieves to collect 5 (maybe another number) pearls, they get to make a wish to the Goddess of this world, and she will make anything possible.

The pearls are used on the characters weapons to level up each time they get a new one. The main character is a sword weilder and gets upgraded whenever he earns a new pearl.

I remember distinctively that the main character and his second (I believe it is a humanoid reptile lizard-like that uses magic and has a haut-de-forme hat) have to climb during the story on a high red mountain plateau like the one in Australia. I believe it is to fight a dragon at the top but am not sure about that info.

Comment: The japanese light novel "Brave Story" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Story) by Miyuki Miyabe matches several of the plot points you mention. The anime and the novel have already been the subject of some questions here (e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161632/story-id-lengthy-ya-fantasy-novel-where-a-teenager-quests-through-a-fictional/162171#162171) 

I only know the anime, but if no one with knowledge of the manga beats me to it, I'll gladly expand this into an answer (unless asking for the manga counts as duplicate of the existing questions).

Comment: Yeeeeees exactly, gosh i'v been searching for days, thank you internet
I have definitely read the manga version, but also do remember a novel version exists as well.

Comment: @Valorum: Done. :)

Answer (score 8):

The japanese light novel ["Brave Story"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Story) by Miyuki Miyabe matches several of the plot points you mention and was adapted as manga. The anime and the novel have already been the subject of some questions here (e.g. [Story ID - Lengthy YA Fantasy Novel where a teenager quests through a fictional country to cure his mother](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161632/)).

Points that match: Visitors to the world Vision will are granted a wish by the goddess of fate. Wataru, the main character of Brave Story, is issued a sword before being sent to Vision. The first person he meets and befriends there is Kee Keema from the lizardlike waterfolk, but I don't recall him wearing a haut-de-forme hat in the anime.